# Looking for old Garageband loop

Tags: garageband

I bought a Macbook Pro in 2005 which got destroyed. I used a glockenspiel loop on garageband and would like to use it again now I"m starting out with Logic x. This is all the info I have. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

First, I know little about Garage Band, but I got it on or with my first Macbook. The old version now shows up in the App Store under the 'Purchased' tab at the top of the page. You could try getting that version again.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is using the  DVD that came with your old mac, the DVD that holds iLife. You should be able to install the old garageband from it and to retrieve from this garageband the free apple loops.

What Scott suggests is a good idea, you just need to download the old Garageband and to download the loop from it. But this solution only works if your destroyed MacBook made the way from its original OSX version to Mavericks that introduces the new GarageBand

If your loop came from an Apple Jam Pack you can still install it on your new Mac, you can easily find it on amazon if you lose the DVD.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a different route and look at what's available right now in the Apple software, there are 6 glockenspiel loops that show up in my GarageBand 10.1.0 loop search, and they came with the Jam Pack Symphony Orchestra, packaged with MainStage 3:

[image]

I hope this helps.